# Denmark Schengen visa reapplication

Tags: visas, schengen, applications, denmark

I would like to re-apply for a Schengen visa for Denmark. Is it okay if a representative takes my application or do I need to bring it in person?

Comment: Where are you from? What happened last time you applied (you write *re-*apply) - those are some (of the) details you'll need to supply before anyone can give you a good answer.

Comment: Aren't you expected to give biometrics?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to take it yourself, in person, according to the [Denmark in the Philippines directives](http://filippinerne.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/visa-and-residence-permit/short-stay/):

> Individuals applying for a Schengen Visa must submit applications personally at the Visa Application Center.